# How to get the local path in RewriteCond?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /projs/CodeIgniterTest

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projs/CodeIgniterTest/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0
```

The `RewriteRule` works correctly, but I can't get the `RewriteCond` line to work with a local path. I want this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
```

But alas `%{REQUEST_URI}` doesn't care much about the `RewriteBase` line and uses the full path. Is there any way to achieve my desired result? I don't want to have to edit the .htaccess file every time I change the project path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0
```

Or just

```
RewriteCond $0 !^index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0
```

Comment: `RewriteCond $0 !^index.php` worked like a charm! But could you explain the `$0` part? I haven't seen mention of anything like it in the RewriteCond documentation

Comment: Apache matches the regex in the rewrite rule, before executing the rewritecond rule(s). RewriteCond can therefor use  $0..9 in the TestString. So in your case $0 contains the path relative to your rewritebase. (It in the first bulletpoint on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)